# Foreign key integration in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have 3 tables named products, products_distribution, region. 
Logic is product has one pkey p_id, region has one pkey r_id, and products_distribution must have one pkey lets say pd_id and 2 foreign keys relating to products and regions.

I can have many products for one region.

I have created unique key for product_id and region id and mentioned foreignkey that related product and region table. But after I created I added product id 7 and region id 7 in product distribution table. Again I wanted to create row with product id 7 and region id 8. But, it says duplicate entry. I have set pd_id (pkey) set to auto increment.

How to integrate foreign key in phpmyadmin in this scenario, so that i can able to set same number of product_id in other rows. But, combination of product_id and region_id in product distribution table must be primary key.

Comment: You need to review how you defined the keys for the table Products_distribution. You should have 1 pk auto-increment and another non-unique index on each of / or the combination of p_id, r_id.

Comment: I dropped the table and created 2 primary keys. Now its fine. But how to create non unique index. I had created foreign keys in relation view tab, i think that created me unique indxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the index creation dialog of phpMyAdmin is set to create a unique index. You just have to change the "index type" selector of this dialog to "index".